# Fedora 23 GUI Login Double Echo

Tags: fedora

I installed a fresh install of Fedora 23 Workstation.  When I try to login using the GUI login screen, each character I type (username and password) are echoed twice, so I cannot login.  I can login via a console terminal just fine.  How do I fix this?

Comment: That's clearly not normal. Can you give some details of your hardware and input settings?

Comment: This is a Dell PowerEdge T320 with a basic USB keyboard and mouse.  This system was running Fedora 18 just fine, but when I did a fresh install of Fedora 23, this issue popped up.  I also noticed that there is no mouse cursor on the login GUI screen either, but I don't remember if there is suppose to be one or not.

Comment: That's very weird. Yes, there should be a mouse cursor there. Can you uncomment the `WaylandEnable=false` line in `/etc/gdm/custom.conf` to see if that helps? (Possibly also enable debugging, while you're there.)

Answer (score 4):

From the comments to the question, uncommenting

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

in `/etc/gdm/custom.conf` solved the problem. That means that this is a bug in Wayland. The default in F23 is to use Wayland for the login screen, and then X after that. We're hoping to enable Wayland more broadly in future releases. It'd really help, therefore, if you could report the bug following the instructions at https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_debug_Wayland_problems#Reporting_the_issue. (Thanks!)